# Disruptor: Gating Sequence

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am studying Disruptor in Java. I do not understand what's meaning of gating sequence. I know it core part is ring buffer and every buffer is associated with a sequence number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the core part of LMAX's implementation is the `Sequencer` and its `Sequence`s. And so the `ringBuffer` implement those. The `gatingSequences` that you are referring to act as a cursor to each `Sequencer` that is "Subscribed" to the targeted `ringBuffer` (or other `Sequencer`). So that's how a `Sequencer` can have multiple cursors for its connected `Sequencers` (and let them touch the next `sequence` by just calling `tryNext()` ).

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of gating sequences is to gate publishers to prevent the `RingBuffer` from wrapping.