# reactor lmax thread dump

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern, project-reactor, lmax

Trying to understand below  (partial) stack trace. Using spring's project reactor 2.0.4.

I got task scheduler threads that are supposed to create tasks and allocate tasks for worker threads. The application is hung at this point (worker threads not logging anything, threaddumps taken at different times always the same etc).

Can I state that the ring buffer is full based on the line :`at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:136)`

if the ring buffer is full why are my worker threads not picking up any of these tasks? Can the ringbuffer state become corrupt?

```
    "task-scheduler-9" prio=10 tid=0x00007f2e78aa7000 nid=0x3a7a waiting on condition [0x00007f2e651b6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:349)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:136)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(MultiProducerSequencer.java:105)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(RingBuffer.java:246)
        at reactor.core.dispatch.WorkQueueDispatcher.allocateTask(WorkQueueDispatcher.java:172)
        at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:117)
        at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.execute(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:133)
        at reactor.spring.core.task.AbstractAsyncTaskExecutor.execute(AbstractAsyncTaskExecutor.java:293)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:324)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)


"pollerExecutor-19" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f2e78ba2000 nid=0x3a6f waiting on condition [0x00007f2e65bc0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x00000007016bd818> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy.waitFor(BlockingWaitStrategy.java:45)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:55)
        at reactor.jarjar.com.lmax.disruptor.WorkProcessor.run(WorkProcessor.java:143)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x00000007011e7058> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at  [MultiProducerSequencer.java # 136](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/f29b3148c2eef3aa2dc5d5f570d7dde92b2f98ba/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/MultiProducerSequencer.java#L136) we see the ring buffer wrap point > a gating sequence. [Disruptor: Gating Sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722809/disruptor-gating-sequence) says this is all about publishers overwriting events that haven't been handled. As you say, why are my worker threads not picking up any of these tasks? I think you need to take a look at your `onEvent` code that implements your `EventHandler<T>`

Comment: thanks for response.  I may be misunderstanding your answer. _publishers overwriting events_: does this actually happen? i.e. do events get overwritten if they are not handled in time? I'd have thought the publishers would be blocked and would just wait for events to be handled.

Comment: Gotta look at [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer#/media/File:Circular_Buffer_Animation.gif) design. The whole point is there is no locking whatever BUT the read / write pointers are handled by the gating sequence stuff. My guess is the Disruptor can be configured to overwrite even if read pointer hasn't moved............. right? The thing is, in your case it looks like you have a consumer event handler problem, not a publisher problem. That's for you to investigate. As you say: why are my worker threads (consumers) not picking up any of these tasks? I don't know...

Comment: I'm using a third party library called reactor that uses lmax so don't have too much control/knowledge over what's going on behind the scenes. I'll have to do some more reading I guess. Thanks for pointers though.